# Completeness relations in propagators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, second-quantization

Let's consider a system of $N$ identical fermions with a time-independent Hamiltonian $H$. We define the Green's function or propagator as

$$G(k_{1}, k_{2}, t, t') = -i \langle \Psi_{0}^{N} | T[c_{k_{1}}(t) c_{k_{2}}^{\dagger}(t')] | \Psi_{0}^{N} \rangle,$$

Since the Hamiltonian is time-idependent, $G$ depends only of the difference $\tau \equiv t - t'$. In general, to get the Spectral representation of the Green's function, the most books use the completeness relations $$\sum_{n,N'} |\Psi_{n}^{N'} \rangle \langle \Psi_{n}^{N'}| = 1$$ into the propagator, to get (let's assume that $t > t'$, or $\tau > 0$, for simplicity)

$$G(k_{1},k_{2}, \tau > 0) = - i \sum_{n} e^{-i(E_{n}^{N+1} - E_{0})\tau} \langle \Psi_{0}^{N}|c_{k_{1}}  |\Psi_{n}^{N+1}\rangle  \langle \Psi_{n}^{N+1}|c_{k_{2}}^{\dagger}  |\Psi_{0}^{N}\rangle .$$

My questions are: Why only the terms with $N' = N + 1$ remains? And, if $H$ is the Hamiltonian of a system of $N$ fermions, why I can apply it to a state of $N + 1$ fermions? Is this because I am using $H$ written in second quantization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c^\dagger$ is a particle creation operator and $|\Psi^N\rangle$ is a N-particle state then $c^\dagger |\Psi^N\rangle$ is an (N+1)-particle state and so dotting with any other particle number vanishes.

The point of second quantization is that you can make things simpler by using operators like $c^\dagger$ which change the particle number, even if for the Hamiltonian you are interested in particle number is something conserved.